# How to test annotation in java using junit

Tags: java, junit, annotations

The class having

```
@Info(name = "ABC", version = "1.1.1")
public class Test implements TestPlugin{
}
```

Where @Info is @interface annotation

I want to write junit test case to verify its @info name and version, what i have passed.

Comment: You want to test that something you hard-coded is right? What did you try?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use reflection for this:

```
Annotation annotation = Test.class.getAnnotation(Info.class);

        if(annotation instanceof Info){
            Info info = (Info) annotation;

            assertEquals("ABC", info.name());
            assertEquals("1.1.1", info.version());
        } else {
            fail("Did not find annotation");
        }
```